# Using a timeout to make a jump function

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am making a game in html5 canvas. I have gotten the player to more. When making the jump function I decided to use a time to reverse the coordinates back to the original after a set time.

The error is nothing happens and upon clicking it again the player goes the other way e.g(down);

```
class Character{
constructor(){
this.x = 50;
this.y = 400;
this.posX=0;
this.posY=0;
this.width;
this.height;
this.hitPoints=1;
this.directionFace="right";
this.jump = false;
this.jumpHeight = 23;
}

 move(e){

    this.x += this.posX;
    this.y += this.posY;

    if(e.keyCode == 37){
    console.log('left');
    this.posX -= 10;
    }

   else if (e.keyCode ==38){

       console.log("UP");

       if (!this.jumping) {

        this.posY -= this.jumpHeight;
        this.jumping = true;

        setTimeout(function(){
            this.posY = this.jumpHeight;          
            this.jumping = false;
        }, 500);
      }
    }

    else if (e.keyCode == 39){

        console.log("right");
         this.posX+=10;
        }

       e.preventDefault();
    }
```

I have another class setup that is setup using setInterval at 50ms and waiting on the keyboard inputs.

Answer (score 1):

The following function has it own `this`, which will not be an instance of you `Character` class.

```
setTimeout(function(){
            this.posY = this.jumpHeight;          
            this.jumping = false;
        }, 500);
```

Try the following code, fat-arrow functions do not have their own `this` context and will capture and preserve the parent one.

```
setTimeout(() => {
            this.posY = this.jumpHeight;          
            this.jumping = false;
        }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the x and y at the start of the move method. Try moving them to the end, after you have made any changes to posX and posY. Also, implement Ivan's change.

You also need to reset posX and posY at the start of the method. Otherwise the character will continue to move up or sideways when any key is pressed.

Comment: x and y are set because I need to make the character show in the correct place to begin on the screen, unless I am wrong on this.

Comment: But, those x and y are only being changed when a key is pressed. So you need to set them after the key press if statements.